# HTML Image with vector overlay that allows zooming and panning with the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Here's a jsfiddle that gives an example of some problems I'm having : http://jsfiddle.net/8LRKW/

In this example, if my rectangle's z-index is negative and the image is upper-most, I can double-click the image and it'll zoom and pan, but if I click my button to make the rectangle upper-most, I can no longer zoom/pan the image - how can I zoom/pan while the canvas is on top ?

Additionally, how do I make the canvas zoom/pan in sync with the image being zoomed/panned?

Also, as a side-note, one problem I've also noticed is that my rectangle initially is hidden and will only appear when canvas gets a mouse-over.  What's going on here, and how do I fix that?

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" id="village">
    <p>
        <img src="http://www.consulenza-web.com/jquery/touchpanview/simpson.jpeg" alt="simpson" width="1920" height="1200" />
    </p>
</div>
<canvas style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:999;" id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
<input style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:350px;z-index:9999;" type="button" value="Toggle Shape z-Index" onclick="$('#myCanvas').css('z-index',$('#myCanvas').css('z-index') * -1);" />


var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                paper.setup(canvas);
                var rectangle = new paper.Rectangle(new paper.Point(50, 50), new paper.Point(150, 100));
                var path = new paper.Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
                path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';

$('#village img').touchPanView({
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            startZoomedOut: true
        });
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I was hoping I could get suggestions on how to go about meeting my requirements (for example, how do I zoom/pan an image when I have a canvas sitting on top of it stealing all the mouse events).

Comment: That isn't a question. That's too broad.

Comment: This isn't a specific question, more a "find a tool for me". Try a couple of the methods and ask here if you hit problems. See #5 here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information

Comment: Added jsfiddle for more specifics.

Comment: If you can edit this question to delete the what-approach part of the question, and just ask how to fix the example, that would be a good specific question that can be taken off hold. If you make that edit, ping me, and I will consider a re-open vote.

Comment: Edited as per request from halfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add pointer-events: none to the style. This fixes it in Firefox and will fix it in other UIs that implement pointer-events.

```
<canvas style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:999;pointer-events:none" id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
```

Comment: Excellent!  That solves one of my problems.  Any idea why the vector graphics don't show until I mouse-over the canvas?